# Type colon (:) with pynput

Tags: python, automation, keyboard, pynput

I am trying to make a little script to automate writing some stuff, but I have found out that if I do

`keyboard.type("Stuff: some more stuff")`

I will get

`Stuff> some more stuff`.

I have tried every character I could think of and it turns out it changes the characters to completely different ones. Is there any way I can insert the colon using pynput?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't type it directly on Parrot OS, so you'd have to do this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(':')
keyboard.release(':')
```

Comment: It might be an OS or module problem, for example i'm using Windows 10 and the pip library version of pynput

Comment: It may be, I'm using Parrot OS (which is Debian based) and that might be interfiering